# Calculating color values in vertex shader?

Tags: webgl

So I'm currently using some noise functions to create some procedural terrain. From how I understand it, we can use a noise function that takes in a 2D vector and returns a float. We can then interpret this float as the "height" of that point in space. We can also interpret this float as the color for the corresponding fragment. As a result, we end up with mountains that are white on the top and black on the bottom.

Right now, I'm essentially doing the same calculation in the vertex and fragment shaders to get the same value:

Vertex shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float time;
uniform float speed;

varying vec3 pos;
varying vec2 vUv;

float random (in vec2 st) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy,
                         vec2(12.9898,78.233)))* 
        43758.5453123);
}

// Based on Morgan McGuire @morgan3d
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dS3Wd
float noise (in vec2 st) {
    vec2 i = floor(st);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // Four corners in 2D of a tile
    float a = random(i);
    float b = random(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = random(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = random(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    vec2 u = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    return mix(a, b, u.x) + 
            (c - a)* u.y * (1.0 - u.x) + 
            (d - b) * u.x * u.y;
}

#define OCTAVES 8
float fbm ( vec2 st) {
    // Initial values
    float value = 0.;
    float amplitud = .5;
    float frequency = 0.;
    //
    // Loop of octaves
    for (int i = 0; i < OCTAVES; i++) {
        value += amplitud * noise(st);
        st *= 2.1;
        amplitud *= .6;
    }
    return value;
}

float pattern( in vec2 p )
  {
      vec2 q = vec2( fbm( p + vec2(0.0,0.0) ),
                     fbm( p + vec2(5.2,1.3) ) );

      vec2 r = vec2( fbm( p + 4.0*q + vec2(1.7,9.2) ),
                     fbm( p + 4.0*q + vec2(8.3,2.8) ) );

      return fbm( p + 4.0*r );
  }

void main(){
    vUv = uv + time;
    pos = position;

    float n = pattern(pos.xy);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position + 
    normal*n*.035, 1.);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float time;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 pos;

float random (in vec2 st) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy,
                         vec2(12.9898,78.233)))* 
        43758.5453123);
}

// Based on Morgan McGuire @morgan3d
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dS3Wd
float noise (in vec2 st) {
    vec2 i = floor(st);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // Four corners in 2D of a tile
    float a = random(i);
    float b = random(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = random(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = random(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    vec2 u = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    return mix(a, b, u.x) + 
            (c - a)* u.y * (1.0 - u.x) + 
            (d - b) * u.x * u.y;
}

#define OCTAVES 8
float fbm ( vec2 st) {
    // Initial values
    float value = 0.;
    float amplitud = .5;
    float frequency = 0.;
    //
    // Loop of octaves
    for (int i = 0; i < OCTAVES; i++) {
        value += amplitud * noise(st);
        st *= 2.1;
        amplitud *= .6;
    }
    return value;
}

float pattern( in vec2 p )
  {
      vec2 q = vec2( fbm( p + vec2(0.0,0.0) ),
                     fbm( p + vec2(5.2,1.3) ) );

      vec2 r = vec2( fbm( p + 4.0*q + vec2(1.7,9.2) ),
                     fbm( p + 4.0*q + vec2(8.3,2.8) ) );

      return fbm( p + 4.0*r );
  }

void main(){
    vec2 q; 
    vec2 r;
    vec2 j = vec2(0., 1.);
    float p = pattern(pos.xy);

    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, vUv + p/5.);

    // gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, p);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(p);
}
```

Both the vertex and fragment shaders call pattern(pos.xy), which yields the same value. So I figured I could make the code more efficient by calculating this value once for each vertex and passing it into the fragment shader using a varying float:

```
//vertex shader
varying float noise;

void main(){
    noise = pattern(position.xy);
    //rest of code
}

//fragment shader
varying float noise;
void main(){
    //do something with noise value
}
```

However, when I try this, the value that gets passed doesn't seem to be the same. The height map disappears completely. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the fragment shader calculates a color for each fragment, not each vertex? What exactly is going on? What are some ways I can optimize this code? I feel like it shouldn't be necessary to repeat so much code.

Comment: What do you mean "the height map disappears completely". Maybe add pictures of the first case and the second case? Your [noise function](http://glslsandbox.com/e#42045.0) seems to have a lot of detail. If you compute that in the fragment shader you'll see that detail between vertices. If you just pass it from the vertex shader you'll just see an interpolated value between each vertex. The further apart the vertices are the less detail you'll see.

Comment: I see. So is there a workaround where I can achieve the same level of detail while avoiding running noise calculations in the vertex and fragment shaders? Originally, my plane looks like this:

https://puu.sh/xdxTL/c7e4ff06da.png

This is when I calculate noise for every vertex and for each fragment. Using Rabbid76's solution below, it seems that I'm getting an interpolated value between each vertex, as you said:

https://puu.sh/xdya2/44bffcd814.png

Is there any way I can achieve the effect in the first screenshot in a more optimized way?

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback! Going forward, I'm considering two approaches to generating said texture. One option is to draw the height map on a plane, screenshot it and use it as a height map/color map at runtime. Another option would be to do the height calculations in Javascript and pass the values into the shaders as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) is executed for each vertex of the vertices of the mesh buffer, the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) is executed at least once for each fragment which is drawn. Output variables from the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) are passed to the next stage of the pipeline.
 If the next stage is the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) (which is the case in WebGL) the output varibales of the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) are interpolated according to there [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) on the rendered primitive, and are passed to the input varibales of the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader).

Note, while `gl_Position` is only calculated once per vertex, `gl_FragColor` is calculated once per fragment. This causes, that the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) defines the geometry and the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) defines the color of the fragment.

For the reason of optimization, you can calculate the height of your height map once per vertex, and let the graphics pipeline do the job to interpolate the height for the coloring of the fragments between the vertices.

Your code should look somehow like this:

*Vertex shader*

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;

uniform float time;
uniform float speed;

varying vec3  pos;
varying vec2  vUv;
varying float mapH;

float pattern( in vec2 p );

void main()
{
    vUv         = uv + time;
    pos         = position;
    mapH        = pattern(pos.xy);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position + normal*mapH*.035, 1.0);
}
```

*Frgament Shader*

```
varying vec2  vUv;
varying vec3  pos;
varying float mapH;

vec3 HeightToRGB(in float H)
{
    float B = abs(H * 5.0 - 3.0) - 1.0;
    float G = 2.0 - abs(H * 5.0 - 2.0);
    float R = 2.0 - abs(H * 5.0 - 4.0);
    return clamp( vec3(R,G,B), 0.0, 1.0 );
}

void main()
{
    vec3 color = HeightToRGB( clamp(mapH, 0.0, 1.0) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );
}
```

Note, I added a function, which colors the height map similar like a rainbow.